I get db.execAsync error even though I am using expo sqlite latest version
I am developing a project with Expo. I am using Expo Sqlite . I created a database . I am using the new version of Expo but I get the following error:
ERROR Failed to initialize database: [TypeError: db.execAsync is not a function (it is undefined)].
By the way, most of the code in App.js is the code I wrote to design the OnBoarding page. But I tried to initialize the database in the 'oninit' property of SqlProvider.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { SQLiteProvider } from 'expo-sqlite';
import OnboardingScreen from './screens/OnboardingScreen';
import Anasayfa from './screens/Anasayfa';
import Liste from './screens/Liste';
import KelimeEkle from './screens/KelimeEkle';
import Quiz from './screens/Quiz';
import DeyimEkle from './screens/DeyimEkle';
import Detay from './screens/Detay';
import { getItem, setItem } from './utils/asyncStorage';
import { initializeDatabase } from './database/database'; // Migration işlemleri için import

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isOnboarding, setIsOnboarding] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const setup = async () => {
      try {
        // Onboarding kontrolü yap
        await checkOnboarding();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Setup sırasında bir hata oluştu:', error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
    setup();
  }, []);

  const checkOnboarding = async () => {
    try {
      const onboarded = await getItem('onboarded');
      setIsOnboarding(onboarded !== '1');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Onboarding kontrolü sırasında bir hata oluştu:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleOnboardingComplete = async () => {
    try {
      await setItem('onboarded', '1');
      setIsOnboarding(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Onboarding tamamlanırken bir hata oluştu:', error);
    }
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <SQLiteProvider databaseName="test.db" onInit={initializeDatabase}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={isOnboarding ? 'OnboardingScreen' : 'Anasayfa'}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name='Anasayfa'
            component={Anasayfa}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name='OnboardingScreen'
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          >
            {props => <OnboardingScreen {...props} onComplete={handleOnboardingComplete} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen name='DeyimEkle' component={DeyimEkle} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name='KelimeEkle' component={KelimeEkle} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name='Quiz' component={Quiz} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name='Liste' component={Liste} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name='Detay' component={Detay} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SQLiteProvider>
  );
}



import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

// Veritabanını başlat
const db = SQLite.openDatabaseAsync('englishDB.db');

// Veritabanını başlatma ve tablo oluşturma
export async function initializeDatabase() {
    try {
        await db.execAsync(`
      PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        english_word TEXT NOT NULL,
        meaning TEXT NOT NULL,
        level TEXT,
        usage_sentence TEXT,
        usage_sentence_meaning TEXT
      );
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS idioms (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        idiom TEXT NOT NULL,
        meaning TEXT NOT NULL,
        usage_sentence TEXT,
        usage_sentence_meaning TEXT
      );
    `);
        console.log('Database and tables created successfully');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to initialize database:', error);
    }
}


Hello,
"[TypeError: db.execAsync is not a function (it is undefined)]."
You are calling a function  which typically doesn't exist.

Hello, I solved my problem as follows, but I am not sure exactly what I did: export async function initializeDatabase(db) . When I put the db into this way, my tables were created.Thank you for your concern.

After wrapping your app with SQLiteProvider and initializing your db like so
<SQLiteProvider databaseName="test.db" onInit={initializeDatabase}>
  /* The rest of your wrapped screens or app*/
</SQLiteProvider>

This means you can access your db anywhere on your app as long as the app is wrapped with the SQLiteProvider
So on your export async function initializeDatabase(db) {}
You will pass the DB parameter without calling the db again so the code will read as:
// Veritabanını başlatma ve tablo oluşturma
export async function initializeDatabase(db) {
 /*The rest of your code*/
}

If you opt to call the db context you can call it as using the useSQLiteContext:
import { SQLiteProvider, useSQLiteContext } from 'expo-sqlite';

Clarity you can refer to this great example
https://github.com/khaoulasdevtutos/listOfStudents/blob/main/App.js
